# How to Run a Java class from another class from another folder

Tags: java, class

I'm making a testing tool. For this, I need to access a class which is present in Test folder within same project.

I've a class mutant.java in src folder. And I've another class TestAll.java which is present in Test folder within same project. I need to access TestAll.java class in mutant.java class. But I can't be able to find a way to do that.

```
public void runTest()
{
    TestAll a=new TestAll();
}
```

When I create an object of TestAll.java class in mutant.java class, It gives me an error and didn't recognize that class. I want to access TestAll.java class but don't know How can I?

Comment: Research the `package` and `import` keywords. Also you should avoid placing `.java` files directly in `src` folder, each class should be placed in some package.

Comment: You shouldn't access Test classes in your application classes under src folders.

Comment: You should rather move your test tool to the `test`dir.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to access TestAll.java class in mutant.java class

No, you need to understand how to properly organize the dependencies within a project.

Your "production" code, that stuff that sits in `src` is **never ever** supposed to use something from the `test` folder. End of story.

Reasoning: `src` represents the content that you "ship" to your customer. That is your product. Your own test code is **not** your product. In order to prevent you from (accidentally) releasing "test stuff" to your customer, you ensure that `src` can't use `test`. That is why any IDE or build tool organizes your project based on that simple rule.

Thus, the real answer is: you should step back, and rethink what you intend to do. The purpose of any test is to prepare some sort of setup, to then run some production code, and verify the expected behavior.

If your current design prevents that, then, as said: stop right there. Ideally, look out for some peer/tutor to sit down with you and rethink your design, and change it accordingly.

Every second you invest into "how do I use stuff from `test` within `src`" is a waste of your energy.

Comment: I applogize, You didn't understand my question.

Comment: @dr.faisu What makes you think so? Read that first in my answer, where I quote your question. You say: the src mutant.java (wrong casing for a class btw) shall use TestAll.java from the test directory. Maybe you wanted to ask something else, but I am pretty confident that my answer talks exactly about the thing you *wrote* in your question. So if something went wrong here, maybe you should step back and re-read your question and fix it.